# Где ошибка в функции?

Tags: javascript

Не работает, если задать в параметре массив. Почему выводит NaN?

```js
function formatDate(date) {
 var toString = {}.toString;
 if (toString.call(date) === '[object Date]') {
  var dd = date.getDate();
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
  
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
  
    var yy = date.getFullYear() % 100;
    if (yy < 10) yy = '0' + yy;
  
    return dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yy;
 }
 else if (typeof date === 'string') {
  date = date.split('-').join();
  return formatDate(new Date(date));
 }
 else if (Array.isArray(date)) {
  date = date.join();
  return formatDate(new Date(date));
 }
 else {
  date = new Date(date*1000);
  date = date.getFullYear() + ', ' + date.getMonth() + ', ' + date.getDate();
  return formatDate(new Date(date));
 }
}

console.log( formatDate('2011-10-02') ); // 02.10.11
console.log( formatDate(1234567890) ); // 14.02.09
console.log( formatDate([2014, 0, 1]) ); // 01.01.14
console.log( formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1)) ); // 01.01.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Upd: прошу прощения, просто формат надо было поправить

```
console.log( formatDate([2014, 01, 01]) ); // 01.01.14
```

Comment: и что будет на выходе?

Comment: поправил, формат передачи даты согласен, был не валиден

Comment: и вообще, всё работет просто изменив формат на нормальный

Comment: да, вероятно..)

Comment: А почему тогда в четвертом случае работает? Когда я сразу передаю 

`console.log( formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1)) );`

Comment: здесь есть небольшая тонкость в new Date(), если передавать строку new Date('2014,1,1') то вы получите январь, а если number new Date(2014,1,1) то февраль. Отсюда выходит, что если передать в строке месяц 0, то в ответ получаете ошибку, т.к. 0 месяца нет )))

Answer (score 0):

ну у тебя строка получается `2014,0,1`, а это не валидный аргумент, наверно надо писать так:

```
if (Array.isArray(date)) {      
    return formatDate(new Date(...date));
}
```

либо писать валидную строку для входа, как в случае с `2011-10-02`

Comment: А почему тогда в четвертом случае работает? Когда я сразу передаю

     `console.log( formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1)) );`

Comment: @Qwerty ну так ты в четвертом случае передаешь отдельные параметры, а тут строку из трех чисел.разница есть передавать `('x y z')` и передавать `(x,y,z)`